# Cannot import QML plugin

Tags: qt, qml

Let's consider an example QML plugin *PluginExample* (see [C++ Plugins for QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-chapter6-plugins-example.html)) created in the directory `$HOME/projects/org/example/PluginExample` (`$HOME/projects` is in `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`).

**pluginexample.pro**:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = PluginExample
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += qt plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = org.example.PluginExample

# Input
SOURCES += \
    pluginexample_plugin.cc \
    myitem.cc

HEADERS += \
    pluginexample_plugin.hh \
    myitem.hh

OTHER_FILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\" \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}
```

**myitem.hh**:

```
#ifndef MYITEM_H
#define MYITEM_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class MyItem : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyItem)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text CONSTANT)

public:
    MyItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    QString text() const;
    ~MyItem();
};

#endif // MYITEM_H
```

**myitem.cc**:

```
#include "myitem.hh"

MyItem::MyItem(QQuickItem *parent):
    QQuickItem(parent)
{
}

MyItem::~MyItem()
{
}

QString MyItem::text() const
{
    return "MyItem";
}
```

**pluginexample_plugin.hh**:

```
#ifndef PLUGINEXAMPLE_PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGINEXAMPLE_PLUGIN_H

#include <QQmlExtensionPlugin>

class PluginExamplePlugin : public QQmlExtensionPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.QQmlExtensionInterface")

public:
    void registerTypes(const char *uri);
};

#endif // PLUGINEXAMPLE_PLUGIN_H
```

**pluginexample_plugin.cc**:

```
#include "pluginexample_plugin.hh"
#include "myitem.hh"

#include <qqml.h>

void PluginExamplePlugin::registerTypes(const char *uri)
{
    // @uri org.example.PluginExample
    qmlRegisterType<MyItem>(uri, 1, 0, "MyItem");
}
```

**qmldir**:

```
module org.example.PluginExample
plugin PluginExample
```

The most part of the plugin's code was auto-generated by the project wizard.

It builds fine, but when I try to `import org.example.PluginExample 1.0` from another project, I get this error:

```
module "org.example.PluginExample" plugin "PluginExample" not found
```

How can I fix that? Do I need to specify additional information to build/locate the plugin?

PS. Qt 5.3, Linux x86_64

---

**EDIT 1**:

I copied `libPluginExample.so` from the build directory (`build-PluginExample-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_GCC_64bit-Debug`) to the source directory (`PluginExample`), and the error disappeared. Is this the best solution?

**EDIT 2**:

To avoid manual copying of the plugin library after each build, the following changes need to be applied to the ***.pro** file (unix-specific):

```
!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    # ...

    unix {
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(COPY_FILE) $$quote($${OUT_PWD}/lib$${TARGET}.so) $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_
    }
}
```

Comment: where is call to registerTypes()?

Comment: @folibis, I din't directly call `registerTypes`. Do I need to? All examples I have seen so far don't do than.

Comment: default QML project come with install rules. Probably it must be in $QTDIR/qml/YourPluginDir/libYourPlugin.so

Comment: @folibis, I think I'm starting to get it. I added a build step which invokes `make install`, then `qmldir` and `libPluginExample.so` was installed in `$QTDIR/qml/org/example/PluginExample`. So I guess I just need to point **QML2_IMPORT_PATH** to `$QTDIR/qml`?